# Why doesn't except ValueError: trigger?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I cannot figure out why my except clause does not trigger in the following:

```
while True:
    userlow = int(raw_input('num please'))
    userhigh = int(raw_input('num please'))
    loopmult = int(raw_input('enter a num please'))
    except ValueError:
        print 'ERROR: Integer only'
    if userlow < userhigh: break
```

This is an excerpt of my code and I was wondering why the except ValueError is not working. The error that I am getting is invalid syntax, and was only there after I added that into my code.  It is not highlighting where my problem is, but if you could please help that would be nice. I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

```
while True:
    try:
        userlow = int(raw_input('num please'))
        userhigh = int(raw_input('num please'))
        loopmult = int(raw_input('enter a num please'))
        if userlow < userhigh: 
            break
    except ValueError:
        print 'ERROR: Integer only'
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 3):

it's used as a `try...except` statement. You don't have a `try:`.

```
while True:
    try:
        userlow = int(raw_input('num please'))
       userhigh = int(raw_input('num please'))
       loopmult = int(raw_input('enter a num please'))
    except ValueError:
        print 'ERROR: Integer only'
    if userlow < userhigh: break
```

Read more about it [from the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Answer (score -1):

"`There is no try`"  :-) literally in your above code. Just fix that.

Comment: You don't deserve an upvote for the answer but much, much kudos. It's brilliant!